# update same variable by multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 html page, page1-4. And global variable stores in js file, i want to update the variable by click yes/no on each of the webpage.
Is there a way to keep the variable ? e.g. store in webrownser or harddisk ?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/counter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Are u in?</h1>
    <!--img tag-->
    <div id="yes">
        <input type="button" name="yes" value="Yes">
    </div>
    <div id="no">
        <input type="button" name="yes" value="No">
    </div>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
            $("#yes").click(function() {
                count = 1; //page2 will getC() and count += 2 and setC(count)
                setC(count);
                window.location.replace("page2.html");//maybe this will clear out something
            });
            $("#no").click(function() {
                window.location.replace("page2.html");
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

------------js file------------------

```
var count;

function setC(c){
    count = c;
}
function getC(){
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `cookie` to store the value across requests. You can use this jQuery plugin that make working with cookies very easy: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Here is a simple example:

**Setting the value**

```
function setC(c){
    $.cookie('the_count', c); //Cookie Key and Cookie Value
}
```

**Getting the value**

```
function getC(){
    return $.cookie('the_count') || 0; //Pass in the cookie key
}
```

There is now no need for the global variable count. You can just use `setC` and `getC`. If you are interested in a slightly more involved solution, you can use AmplifyJS instead of the jQuery cookie plug-in. AmplifyJS will use `HTML5 local storage` when available and fall back to cookies if the browser does not support local storage. More info here: http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

Comment: Each browser will have it's own set of cookies. So, it will carry over page requests however it will not persist across browsers. You can change `return $.cookie('the_count');` to `return $.cookie('the_count') || 0;` this will return a default value of 0 when there is nothing set.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies, like Paul mentioned, is a great solution. However, if you want to get your hands dirty, you could look into the [HTML5 localStorage API](http://24ways.org/2010/html5-local-storage), which is perfect for this kind of thing.

If someone is using a browser that doesn't support it, can always fall back to cookies, but keep in mind they may have cookies rejected, which will create problems for you, if the site is depending on this.

Keep in mind if you are developing locally on file:// urls, then the storage won't persist across pages as it does on domains - each file url is sandboxed and unable to access other files storage.

Comment: If you want to get your hands dirtier (and real time), look at node.js and socket.io :)